# How to create color variables dynamically in sass

Tags: sass

Let say I have color variables $blue, $red, $green, etc
And I want each color to have few tones.

```
$blue-lighter: lighten($blue, 50%);
$blue-light: lighten($blue, 25%);
$blue-dark: darken($blue, 25%);
$blue-darker: darken($blue, 50%);
```

Is there a way to create these variables on the fly in order to avoid to have all these **tones** variables hard coded?

I tried to do like that, but it gives me error

```
@each $color, $value in $colors {
  $#{$color}_lighter: lighten($value, 50%) ;
  $#{$color}_light:   lighten($value, 25%) ;
  $#{$color}_dark:    darken($value, 25%) ;
  $#{$color}_darker:  darken($value, 50%) ;
}
```

Comment: Without creating them on the fly, how would you feel about using a function instead ?

Comment: I am not expert in sass. I tried to do some, but it gives me error `Expected identifier.` I add my experiment in topic

Comment: I know that you want to create variable on the fly, but let's do it in a different way. I you create a function `@function lighter($color) { @return lighten($color, 50%) }`, you can then use it like this: `html { color: lighter($red); }`. This way, you just need to create 4 functions, lighter, light, darker, dark.

Comment: Not exactly how I expect to do, but this is also working. Thanks